# Maven App Engine Configuration problem Java 8 (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I'm having some issues with Eclipse, Maven, Java 8 and App Engine Standard Environment project.

After creating another project that requires Java 11, it seems that Eclipse or Maven is struggling to work correctly.

The main error I get in markers Eclipse tab that is impeding me to deploy or launch a local environment is:
**App Engine Java Standard Environment JRE8 requires Dynamic Web Module with version matching expression "[2.5-3.1]"**

[image]

Eclipse Project Facets are correctly configured. Dynamic Web Module version 2.5, App Engine Standar using Java 1.8

[image]

Project build path points to jdk1.8.0_211. Compiler too.

[image]

Nothing changed in the project recently. Error appeared after doing Maven -> Update project.

I tried every change suggested in Google but nothing seems to change.

I tried creating another workspace which worked (even reinstalling Eclipse) for 24 hours. After that, sudenly the error appeared again.

What should I try next? This problem is stopping me from working...

**Edit**:
Maven commands work fine, clean, install, package.
Also deploying (appengine:deploy) works but throws many errors of missing classes.

I cannot deploy the application through Google Cloud Tools extension in Eclipse because of Maven configuration errors.
Local server (Eclipse launching) throws many exceptions of missing classes.
Local server (Maven launching) fails to run with this error:
[image]
**File exists**

Maven Update project and install package outputs different compiled classes at target directory, don't know why

PD: Replaced some project naming with placeholders.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>artifact-module</artifactId>
    <name>name-module</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <appengine.maven.plugin.version>2.4.0</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endpoints.project.id>projectid</endpoints.project.id>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    </properties>
    
    <prerequisites>
      <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>20.4.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-management-control-appengine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.88</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-admin-directory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-admin-directory</artifactId>
            <version>directory_v1-rev110-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-calendar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev20191117-1.30.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-people -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-people</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20190910-1.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev20191108-1.30.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20190602-1.30.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gdata/core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>5.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework-auth -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework-auth</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>     
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mailjet</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailjet-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
           
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</hostname>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- deploy configuration -->
                    <version>1</version> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you provide some reproduction steps and your pom file? Also it would be helpful, if possible, for you to try to run your application from a shell in order to discard any issue with Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the response, please check the edit

Comment: I suggest you to check this github [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2285#issuecomment-322934737) in which they discuss a similar problem. Could you check that your file ```.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml``` is properly builded?

Comment: Hi, I will check the issue. Regarding your question, it is fine, I found people with problems because of this file being corrupted, but mine is completely fine